# When running conda install the system is throwing Permission Error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

OS: Windows 10 Pro; 
 
conda version => 4.8.3 
 
Command trying to execute=> conda create -n tf-gpu python=3.6

Error is:
 
Preparing transaction: done 
                                                                                                                                         Verifying transaction: done 
                                                                                                                                            Executing transaction: done 
                                                                                                                                            ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::python-3.6.10-h9f7ef89_1'. 
 Rolling back transaction: done 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\tf-gpu\python.exe'                                                                                    ()

How to fix this issue?

I have tried running in Admin console and reinstalling anaconda; still the same problem.

Comment: Unless you are managing a multi-user Conda installation, it is almost always preferable to install Mini- or Anaconda as a non-admin.

Comment: How did you install Conda?